# Navigate to different screen using header button doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and was trying to allow user to navigate to another screen from a headerRight button. Looked around and found a recommended answer but was hit with another issue. Is there another way to navigate to other screens using headerRight?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERNCR.png)

and this is my code snippet:

[attempt to navigate using right header button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjNGC.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

What you described is absolutely possible, the API has just changed slightly with the beta.9 release. This should work for you, given the code example you linked to

```
const routeConfiguration = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerRight: () => <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn') } />
    }),
  },
  // ...
};
```

The [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack) have been updated with the new API.

Comment: Verified and confirmed working thanks! Didn't notice the api changes. This answer should aid the rest who just upgraded to the new version and have the same issue as me.

Answer (score 1):

The code works without arrow function after 'headerRight: '

```
const routeConfiguration = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerRight: <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn') } />
    }),
  },
  // ...
};
```